# Ao enviar formulário, como aparecer o resultado referente as opções escolhidas?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Olá, pessoal!
Minha dúvida é basicamente o seguinte.
Tenho um formulário, onde as pessoas colocam seu nome, telefone, cidade, opção de produto (imóvel/automóvel). Ao clicar em enviar, eu preciso que apareça uma tela com uma tabela de valores referente a sua opção de produtos.

Por exemplo, preenchi os dados e coloquei imóvel. Ao enviar o formulário, aparecerá a tabela de valores.

Obs: O código do formulário está pronto e ele já está enviando os dados para o código de barras. Entretanto, eu preciso saber como fazer aparecer a opção de produto que o cliente escolheu, ao preencher ele.

Como posso fazer isso?

```
      <h2>SIMULE AGORA SEU CONSÓRCIO!</h2><br/><br/>
  <div class="col-md-6">
         <img src="img/simule.jpg" class="imagem" alt="Vitor Cons�rcios">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <form action="simulador.php" method="post" name="dados" id="dados" onSubmit="return validaform()">
        <div class="col-md-5 esquerda">
                       Selecione o bem<br/>
                       <select name="tipo" type="text" class="contat3" placeholder="Selecione o bem">
                       <option value="Im�vel"" 
                       style="background-color: #fff;">Imóveis</option>
                       <option value="Autom�vel"" 
                       style="background-color: #fff;">Automóveis</option>
                       <option value="Moto" style="background-color: #fff;">Motos</option>
                      </select><br/>
                     Selecione o plano<br/>
                     <select name="plano" type="text" class="contat3">
                       <option value="Crédito"" 
                     style="background-color: #fff;">Crédito</option>
                       <option value="Parcela"" 
                     style="background-color: #fff;">Parcela</option>
                     </select><br/>


                     <input name="valorcon" type="text" id="valorcon" class="contat3"  placeholder="Digite o valor" maxlength="1000" /><br/>



                     <input name="nomecon" type="text" id="nomecon" class="contat3"  placeholder="Nome"  maxlength="1000" /><br/>





                     <input name="telefone" type="text" 
                      onkeypress="Mascara('TEL',this,event);"
                     type="text" id="telefone" class="contat3"  placeholder="Telefone" />

                     <!--- 
                     <input name="tel2" type="text" id="tel2" onkeypress="Mascara('TEL',this,event);" /><br/>
                     --->



                     <input name="emailcon" type="text" id="emailcon" class="contat3"  placeholder="E-mail"  maxlength="1000" /><br/>



                     <input name="cidadecon" type="text" id="cidadecon" class="contat3"  placeholder="Cidade"  maxlength="1000" />


                     <br/><br/><br/>
                     <a id="enviar-form" class="button solid-color" href="#">Enviar</a>
                     <input type="submit" id="enviar-form-btn" style="display: none;" />

        </div>         
   </form>
```

Comment: No simulador.php vai chegar os dados, trate os dados e monte a tela que precisa.

Comment: Oi @GlenysMitchell, não entendi muito bem.

Comment: todos os dados do formulário são enviados para a página simulador.php. Lá você recebe esses dados e com base no que foi digitado monta a tela.

Comment: @GlenysMitchell E como faço para que quando o visitante escolher a opção de produto, aparecer a tabela referente a ela?

Comment: Forma com banco: Se você quer fazer em uma tela só, terá que usar ajax, ou post/get do jquery para fazer isso.

Comment: Forma sem banco de dados: Os objetos a serem carregados já devem existir na tela, porém escondidos, e só quando o usuário escolher essa opção, deve aparecer o trecho da tela que quer exibir. Qual das duas?

Comment: @GlenysMitchell Você pode me fornecer um código de exemplo?

Comment: Vou montar uma resposta, um momento.

Comment: Certo, @GlenysMitchell. Estou no aguardo!

Comment: Seu site tem jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Se essa tabela vier com informações de um banco de dados, sugiro que faça com jquery e conexao via post/get, este link tem dois exemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Se não precisar disso você terá uma tabela escondida pelo atributo hidden:

```
<select name="tipo" type="text" class="contat3" placeholder="Selecione o bem" id="tipo">
    <option value="Imóvel" style="background-color: #fff;">Imóveis</option>
    <option value="Automóvel" style="background-color: #fff;">Automóveis</option>
    <option value="Moto" style="background-color: #fff;">Motos</option>
</select>
<div id="tabela_escondida" hidden>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>colunas</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>valores</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

E um jquery ou javascript para fazer a tabela aparecer quando a opção for escolhida.
Exemplo com jquery:

```
$('#tipo').change(function(){ //ativa a função ao mudar o select
    var escolha = $("#tipo option:selected").val();
    alert('o usuario escolheu:' + escolha); //teste para ver o que o usuário escolheu
    if(escolha == 'A')
    {
        $('#tabela_escondida').show(); //mostra a div que tem a tabela dentro
    }
    else
    {
        $('#tabela_escondida').hide(); //esconde a div que tem a tabela dentro
    }
});
```

PS: pode remover a linha do alert inteira, serve apenas para teste.

se for para fazer em um segundo momento, dentro do simulador.php você colocará uma condicional.

```
if($_POST['tipo'] == 'Imóvel') hearder('location: paginaComAtabelaA.php');
else if($_POST['tipo'] == 'Automóvel') hearder('location: paginaComAtabelaB.php');
```

Comment: Oi Glenys, muito obrigado! Mas essa tabela no caso só pode aparecer quando a pessoa clica em enviar. Nesse caso, o que devo fazer?

Comment: Nesse caso, insisto, você terá que fazer na tela do simulando.php, ou uma tela após isso.

Comment: Bom, eu já tenho as páginas/telas prontas, com a tabela pra cada. Porém, não sei como fazer ele direcionar para elas de acordo com a opção de bem/produto escolhido.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh siiim, vou editar resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! No caso é só colocar o último código né?

Comment: Sim, mas antes você tem que ver para onde essa página simulador.php está mandando o usuário.

Comment: Não deu muito certo :/

Comment: Glenys, existe alguma forma de contato com você? Preciso muito resolver isso, se for necessário até pago um valor para você!

Comment: Vamos tentar resolver por aqui. Quantas linhas tem na sua página simulador.php?

Comment: Na página possui 424 linhas.

Comment: Me passa o seu e-mail ou whats.